# ASP.NET - IF Statement in Listview doesnt work on aspx page, is there an alternative?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have bound a DataSet to a ListView. In the ListView ItemTemplate, if a row value is empty, I do not want it, or the `<td>` element it is enclosed in to display.

In my code, the first row value will display. However, when I try to use the If statement on the second `<td>` element, that will not display.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"> </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"> </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <td> 
            <%# Eval("textItem1") %>
        </td>

        <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textItem2){ %>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("textItem2") %>
        </td>
        <%} %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

That If statement works in an aspx page if its NOT being used in a ListView, Repeater, or GridView (or does it?). I need to be able to check if that string row value is empty and not display it or the `<td>` element it is enclosed in. I am not against a solution that uses code-behind. Is there another way to do this then my attempt?

Comment: Can you post your code behind, where you are assigning datasource to listview.

Comment: The code behind that fills the dataset is irrelevant so I didn't add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I used a pretty simple method solution..

In the above code, I swapped out this...

```
    <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textItem2){ %>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("textItem2") %>
    </td>
    <%} %>
```

For this...

```
<%# writeText(Eval("textItem2").ToString())%>
```

And placed this method in the code behind...

```
    public string writeText(string kiss)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(kiss))
            return "<td> " + kiss + "</td>";
        else
            return null;

    }
```